# POST form to url string query

Tags: php, html

I was wondering how to POST a form to a string query url.
I know how to post a form, however, my urls are using string queries, and i cannot seem to post to the page i require.

My page url is along the lines of:
    ...  Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=NYC

Using:

```
 ...  Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=<?php echo $admin_Franchise?>
```

I have tried:

```
 <form id="myform " class="Form" method="post"  
 action="Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=
 <?php echo $admin_Franchise?>" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The page posts to Main_Franchise_Details.php, instead of

```
    Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=NYC
```

, for instance I have looked online but cannot find anything, any sugguestions.

Comment: Because anything after ? is a $_GET variable. Your form posts to Main_Franchise_Details.php with $_GET variable Franchise

Comment: are you sure that $admin_Franchise  has the value NYC? Why don't you try to hardcode it first to test (using Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=NYC instead)

Comment: Ditto with @TheDrot, all your form inputs will be available as `$_POST['inputname']` but the franchise will be in `$_GET['Franchise']`

Comment: @TheDrot  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Form:
      
           action="receiver.php?variable_B=Im_a_get_variable" 
           accept-charset="utf-8">
           
      (etc ...)

put in receiver.php:

```
 echo '<pre> POST VARS: '; 
 print_r($_POST);
 echo 'GET VARS: '; 
 print_r($_GET);
```

You'll see variable_B under $_GET and variable_A under $_POST.
Note that you should *url_encode()* all $_GET vars before sending and *url_decode()* when you read them:

```
 action="receiver.php?variable_B=<?= urlencode('Im a GET var")
```

and in receiver.php:

```
 $variable_B = urldecode($_GET['variable_B']);
```